# How to fix "REQUEST_DENIED" while getting current location in cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, cordova, geolocation

I am trying get current location with address by using Cordova geolocation plugin . but i am getting   below error message. 
{error_message: "You must use an API key to authenticate each reque…, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account", results: Array(0), status: "REQUEST_DENIED"}
error_message: "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account"
results: []
status: "REQUEST_DENIED"

for getting current location. below code i am using please correct my code

$scope.init = function () {

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

function onDeviceReady() {


    if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {

    } else {

    }
    var networkConnection = navigator.connection.type;

    if (networkConnection != null) {

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }
    else {
        alert('Please check your network connection and try again.');
    }
}

function success(position) {

    var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    getDetails(latitude, longitude);
}

function error(error) {
    alert('Please check your network connection and try again.');
}

function getDetails(latitude, longitude) {

    var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&sensor=false";
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {

        console.log(data);

    });
}
```

Please correct my code i expected out put current location with address. Thanks for advance.

Comment: **You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs.** I wonder how this could be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

`You must use an API key`

When you signed up for the maps platform, you should have gotten an access key, which you need to pass with every request to authenticate.

Now, as far as i can see, you don't have that token on your URL parameters. ( You may need to send it with the request headers, check the API docs on how it expects it)

EDIT:

This is the format:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap
```

Try this:

```
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?key= "+"ADD YOUR KEY HERE" + "&sensor=false";
```

Also, try using template strings rather than having 10s of + in your string

Comment: Thanks for responding . for signed up it is asking some amount . can i get free one ?

Comment: I haven't used the Google maps API but as far as I know, it's not free. If you are a student, check if that have any promotions and such. Otherwise, try OpenStreetMap API

Comment: @DoddaNaveenkumar you get $200 of free monthly credit with each Maps Platform account. What about reading the documentation?

Comment: I created api key and when i am hit frist time  url in post man gettig success response.,same url hitted second time i got below errror message:{
    "error_message": "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API. If you did not set a custom daily request quota, verify your project has an active billing account: http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
    "results": [],
    "status": "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=17.447412,78.376228&key=AIzaSyBtVPIGYfvFcUvsQML7RH6qN1H7v95ijKY

Comment: Well... Do you have an active billing account?

Comment: @MrUpsidown i want opensource key .is there any away for achiving this one

Comment: @Codeviews No. i created free trail